# cannot add local k8s as cloud in juju

Tags: linux, kubernetes, maas, juju

I have a three node cluster k8s which has been setup via kubeadm, I just heard about juju recently and I’m completely new. what I want is that to register my local k8s into my local juju node but as long as I go for registration I come across the following error.

```
nasri@juju:~$ add-k8s kubeadm-cluster --storage=openebs-hostpath
```

here I can see juju is trying to connect to 10.96.39.217 where as it is a ClusterIP thus it is private and inaccessible from my machine, but why? after a period it ends up with the error that cannot access to the k8s.

```
nasri@juju:~$ juju bootstrap kubeadm-cluster
Creating Juju controller “kubeadm-cluster” on kubeadm-cluster
Fetching Juju Dashboard 0.3.0
Creating k8s resources for controller “controller-kubeadm-cluster”
Starting controller pod
Bootstrap agent now started
Contacting Juju controller at 10.96.39.217 to verify accessibility…
ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: dial tcp 10.96.39.217:17070: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Hi AliReza, welcome to S.F. No one an help you without more specifics about your circumstance since we don't know if 10.96.39.217:17070 is right or wrong or what it represents. Have you perhaps increased the juju logging verbosity to see how it arrived at that host and port combination?

Comment: @mdaniel it seems there is an open bug related to this problem in juju community, hope they fix it soon.

Comment: Given the purpose of this site is to _help others_, it would be polite if you edited your comment to link to the bug you found, in order to help anyone who finds this question in the future

Comment: @mdaniel the bug link is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1905320